# How to Implemanting putExtras SQLite in action menu toolbar Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-actionbar

I have read many tutorial about CRUD SQLite, but most of them use Cursor to get values data and Button to call EditScreen. Any one lead me how to implementing i.putExtras in my Edit Menu Toolbar, please? I want to show again my data in EditText Form.

```
   public class DetailStaffActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private DBHandler dbHandler;
        private TextView txt_resultnomor, txt_resultnama, txt_resulttempatlahir, txt_resulttanggallahir;

        private List<Staff> staffList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.staff_details);

            dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);

            //ambil data
            Intent i=getIntent();
            final String nomor=i.getExtras().getString("nomor");
            final String nama=i.getExtras().getString("nama");
            final String tempatlahir = i.getExtras().getString("tempat_lahir");
            final String tanggallahir=i.getExtras().getString("tanggal_lahir");

            //inisialisasi dulu
            txt_resultnomor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_resultnomor);
            txt_resultnama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_resultnama);
            txt_resulttempatlahir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_resulttempatlahir);
            txt_resulttanggallahir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_resulttanggallahir);

            //set inisial dengan data yang telah diambil di dengan intent
            txt_resultnomor.setText(nomor);
            txt_resultnama.setText(nama);
            txt_resulttempatlahir.setText(tempatlahir);
            txt_resulttanggallahir.setText(tanggallahir);

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.action_edit) {
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) { //here, error when set position in this menu//
                           // TODO Handle item click
                           Intent in = new Intent(this, UpdateStaffActivity.class);
                Staff staff = staffList.get(position); 
                String getNama = staffList.get(position).getNama();
                in.putExtra("nama", getNama);
                startActivity(in);
                return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
                return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                // Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
                //startActivity(i);
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }      
    }
```

Please, how implementing putExtras in

```
if (id == R.id.action_edit) { }
```

I got error when set position in this menu. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Uhm, how should i say, i dont know how to get value of my SQLite by implement putExtras in action_edit_menu. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You already starting `UpdateStaffActivity` from ` if (id == R.id.action_edit)` then what is your question?

Comment: getting error in 'position', any sugestion?

Comment: What is `position` show more code where you have declared and using `position` variable

Comment: Actually, i just try to make the same thing like when i click one  of my recyclerview. ' recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                       public void onItemClick(View view, int position)' . But I found myself failed when try this in my action menu toolbar. So i ask how to get values using putExtras in menu toolbar.

Comment: Edit your other code also in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this line

```
 public void onItemClick(View view, int position) { //here, error when set position in this menu//
                               // TODO Handle item click
                               Intent in = new Intent(this, UpdateStaffActivity.class);
                    Staff staff = staffList.get(position);
String getNama = staffList.get(position).getNama();
```

And write like this.

```
if (id == R.id.action_edit) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(this, UpdateMuriddActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("nomor", txt_resultnomor.getText().toString());
                    in.putExtra("nama", txt_resultnama.getText().toString());
                    in.putExtra("tempat_lahir", txt_resulttempatlahir.getText().toString());
    startActivity(in);
```

Hope its help.